# Do I have to implement a Dispose method in this kind of custom object?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, dispose

### First example

```
public class GameObject
{
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 scale;
    Color color;
    Texture2D atlas_reference;
    Rectangle source_rectangle;

    public GameObject()
    {
        //...
        // atlas_reference is a reference to the texture loaded in "LoadContent" in the main XNA's
        // loop
    }

    // ...
    // ...
    // ...

    public void Update(GameTime dt)
    { 
        //...
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spritebatch)
    { 
        //...
    }
}
```

Should I implement a Dispose method?

```
public void Dispose()
{
    atlas_reference.Dispose(); // ?
}
```

I think no because I would have put the method where it is loaded. Here, in this class, it just gets a reference. Am I wrong?
Maybe I just need to do: `atlas_reference = null;` ?

### Second example

```
public class GameWorld
{
    List<GameObject> game_objects;
    const int obj_number = 1000;

    public GameWorld()
    {
        //...

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
            game_objects[i] = new GameObject(); 

        // ...
    }

    // ...
    // ...
    // ...

    public void Update(GameTime dt)
    { 
        //... loop through the list and update every one
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spritebatch)
    { 
        //... loop through the list and draw every one
    }
}
```

Here I think I should implement Dispose because I am generating some object, so:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    for (int i = obj_number; i >= 0; --i)
        game_objects[i].Dispose();
}
```

But I know that GameObject's dispose method doesn't dispose anything, so should I implement it anyway?

What's the correct thing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you and I are good friends, and one day you come to me and ask to borrow my lawnmower.  Of course I agree; you're my friend, after all, and I expect you to treat my property with the appropriate respect.

A few days later I need to mow my lawn, so I come over to your house and ask you to return my lawnmower.  "Sorry," you say, "I can't."

"Why not?" I ask.

"Well, I took it out back behind the shed and set it on fire."

This is what you are proposing in your first example.  You're loading `asset_reference` in your `Game` object, presumably through its content manager.  In XNA, *the content manager owns the assets it loads*.  It stores them in an internal cache so that it doesn't have to reload them every time you ask for them.  So if you do this:

```
var resource = content.Load<Foo>("bar").Baz();
resource.Dispose();
content.Load<Foo>("bar").Baz();
```

The second call to `Baz()` is almost certainly going to throw an `ObjectDisposedException`!  You're trying to mow your lawn with the burnt-out lawnmower that your crazy neighbor left behind.

Objects should manage the lifetimes of resources *that they own*.  In the same way that you have no right to torch my lawnmower, another class has no right to torch the resources it's been given *unless you explicitly transfer ownership of the resource*.

The second example is closer to what I would consider proper--an object is disposing the resources that it created and therefore owns--but if you know that the `Dispose()` method on `GameObject` doesn't do anything, then why does it implement `IDisposable` at all?

Comment: +1 This is a really good explanation of *why* he shouldn't be implementing it.

Comment: Despite the name, the purpose of `Dispose` is not to *destroy* resources, but *release* them. If one borrows a library book from a friend, calling `Dispose` on the `Book` object wouldn't incinerate the book to which the `Book` object holds a reference, but rather return it to the library. If the friend hadn't finished reading the book, the friend would be annoyed at having to check out the book again. If, however, the friend had finished reading the book, he would get rather annoyed if the library started charging him late fees for a book that was waiting on your table for him to pick up.

Comment: If my friend is loaning me his book, it's not my responsibility to return it to the library for him.  It's my responsibility to return it _to my friend_ so that _he_ can return it to the library, or do whatever else he needs to do with it.  Whether `Dispose()` _releases_ or _frees_ or _destroys_ resources seems irrelevant to me (although in practice, I know of very few scenarios in .NET where objects which have been disposed can be reused, so it seems like a distinction without much of a difference).

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) you only need to implement IDisposable to release *unmanaged* resources. XNA takes care of the content pipeline, so you don't need to worry about your Texture2D.

The reference(s) held by your object will be nulled on destruction, so you don't need to worry about that either. C# uses a reference counted garbage collector, so once the count reaches 0 it will automatically be collected.

To quote it directly:

> You should implement IDisposable only if your type uses unmanaged resources directly.

Comment: Is there an example of unmanaged resource that I can have in my class? A RenderTarget2D in which I draw a texture is a good example? Is there something else?

Comment: @misiMe A good example is the `Bitmap` class, which just wraps a GDI bitmap. You can get very large memory leaks if you forget to dispose it! I don't know of any for XNA off the top of my head though, sorry.

Comment: What happens when an exception is thrown while allocating memory for something? In C++ the exception will flow through the scope and call the destructor of objects with a destructor... Here will it call Dispose?

Comment: @misiMe, If it implements IDisposable, I would imagine that it would be called, yes. In general you don't need to worry about it since the GC will collect it. Given that I'm not completly sure, you should probably have exception-safe constructors :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, if your class contains members which are `IDisposable`, you should also make your class implement `IDisposable` and call `Dispose()` on all disposable members in your classes `Dispose()` method.

Comment: That is not correct. `Using an object that implements IDisposable
Implement IDisposable only if you are using unmanaged resources directly. If your app simply uses an object that implements IDisposable, don't provide an IDisposable implementation. Instead, you should call the object's IDisposable.Dispose implementation when you are finished using it.`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: But given that a member of my class is `IDisposable`, wouldn't that indicate that it uses unmanaged resources and needs to have its `Dispose` method called once I'm done using it? And wouldn't I be done using it once the instance of my class is done being used and has its `Dispose` method called?

Comment: Not necessarily. You could be done with a `Stream` once you read your relevant data and can be disposed long before the object containing it has finished its lifetime. That quote was taken from MSDN and is the recommanded approach of using `IDisposable`

Comment: It should be pointed out that the guideline is exactly that, a guideline, and there many cases where it absolutely makes sense to implement `IDisposable` even if you're only indirectly referencing unmanaged resources.  Consider the example of `ContentManager`, which implements `IDisposable` in such a way that it calls `Dispose()` on all of the assets in its cache.  A better guideline would be:  implement `IDisposable` when your class owns unmanaged resources, directly or otherwise, with a lifetime commensurate with the class itself.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov He is specifically saying a "member" of the class. If there is an `IDisposable` object that is a "member" of the class, in that it will live and die with the object, then yes, construct one in the constructor, and dispose of it in the Dispose method.